# "obvious how ..." vs "obvious of how ..."

Tags: prepositions, difference, collocations

An example of "obvious how ..." from [Definition of obvious adjective from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/obvious?q=obvious):

> - obvious how, what, etc.
>   **It was far from obvious how they were going to get off the island.**

An example of "obvious of how ..." from [a video of Khan Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8qtbGMB2gI&ab_channel=KhanAcademy&t=177) at around 3:00:

> This is a one minus cosine squared theta, so **it's not completely obvious yet of how you can simplify it**, until you realize that this could be viewed as a difference of squares.

#### Question

- Is there any difference between "obvious how ..." and "obvious of how ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Obvious of how" is not correct. It may have been a slip of the tongue.